# Make all subcategories use the template of its category parent?

Tags: categories, templates

How can I make all subcategories use the template of its category parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a code I used to do it:

```
// make category use parent category template
function load_cat_parent_template($template) {

    $cat_ID = absint( get_query_var('cat') );
    $category = get_category( $cat_ID );

    $templates = array();

    if ( !is_wp_error($category) )
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";

    $templates[] = "category-$cat_ID.php";

    // trace back the parent hierarchy and locate a template
    if ( !is_wp_error($category) ) {
        $category = $category->parent ? get_category($category->parent) : '';

        if( !empty($category) ) {
            if ( !is_wp_error($category) )
                $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";

            $templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";
        }
    }

    $templates[] = "category.php";
    $template = locate_template($templates);

    return $template;
}
add_action('category_template', 'load_cat_parent_template');
```

Comment: Was able to use take this idea and implement a tweaked version on our site, thanks!

Comment: was using the above fine until i realised it wasn't filtering the category's sub content. It always loads the parent categories posts. ie /events/ loads events but /events/exhibitions/ also just loads /events/.

How can we get it to load the parent category template but the sub category's

Comment: Use this solution below, it works exactly right, because if there's a category-{slug}.php page for child, it uses that, otherwise uses category-{slug}.php of parent category.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Crabbe had the same issue I had. Found [this site](http://www.kristinfalkner.com/2011/08/a-super-helpful-function/) that has some code that will look for and use a parent category's template file whilst showing the appropriate posts.

I've updated it to support slugs in the file name (not just the category ID).

```
// Use a parent category slug if it exists
function child_force_category_template($template) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $category = get_category($cat);

    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category->cat_ID . '.php') ) {
        $cat_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category ->cat_ID . '.php';
    } elseif ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category->slug . '.php') ) {
        $cat_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category ->slug . '.php';
    } elseif ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category->category_parent . '.php') ) {
        $cat_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $category->category_parent . '.php';
    } else {
        // Get Parent Slug
        $cat_parent = get_category($category->category_parent);

        if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $cat_parent->slug . '.php') ) {
            $cat_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $cat_parent->slug . '.php';
        } else {
            $cat_template = $template;
        }

    }

    return $cat_template;
}
add_action('category_template', 'child_force_category_template');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a filter hook

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_template/

```
/**
 * Retrieve path of category-videos.php template for 'videos' subcategories
 * Filtered via 'category_template' hook
 *
 * @param string Full path to category template file.
 *
 * @return string Full path to category template file.
 */
function get_category_videos_template( $template ) {
  $category_ID = intval( get_query_var('cat') );
  $category = get_category( $category_ID );
  $parent_ID = $category->parent;
  $parent_category = get_category( $parent_ID );
  /**
   * Check wheter the $parent_category object is not a WordPress Error and its slug is 'videos'
   */
  if ( !is_wp_error( $parent_category ) AND $parent_category->slug == 'videos' ) {
    /**
     * Check if the template file exists
     *
     */
    if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $parent_category->slug . '.php' )) {
      return TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $parent_category->slug . '.php';
    }
  } else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'get_category_videos_template' );
```