# one category template for multiple categories

Tags: categories, templates

i have category-events.php to list my posts tagged 'events' but it wont work for 'events' child categories.

ie i have some posts tagged 'events' and one of events' children 'exhibition'. I thought it would use category-events.php automatically but it doesn't. Is this possible as i want to user category-events.php for several of 'events' child categories.

hope that makes sense and any pointers welcome.

dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah - found it here!

[Make all subcategories use the template of its category parent?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/how-can-i-make-all-subcategories-use-the-template-of-its-category-parent)

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

First paste this code in your theme's functions.php

```
function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ){
    foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
        // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
        $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category');
        if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then on your category.php or archive.php (depends on your theme) at the very top add

```
<?php if (post_is_in_descendant_category(33)){
 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-events.php'); 
 exit;
} ?>
```

and change 33 to the ID of the 'events' category.

What it does is check if the current category is a child category of events and if so it uses the right theme file.

Comment: was using the above fine until i realised it wasn't filtering the category's sub content. It always loads the parent categories posts. ie /events/ loads events but /events/exhibitions/ also just loads /events/.

How can we get it to load the parent category template but the sub category's